# Include Files in Yii

Tags: php, yii, swiftmailer

I am building an application in Yii that used the SwiftMailer Extension. The SwiftMailer examples show that I should include all of the information in the controller file however would it not be more organized and better to put all of the information for the email in a seperate file and include that file?

If yes, what would be the best way to include that file? I am used to just using the include function but I am assuming with Yii it should be its own class under the components folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya, you probably want to make a custom class and put your SwiftMailer function in there, as well as any related functions, as appropriate. You can either put it in your components directory or a custom "classes" directory depending on how yo want to import it.

In that class, you can include the SwiftMailer libary (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661736/dropbox-for-yii) for an example of how), in your constructor function or similar.